# I used Stargazer in Python. How to convert output to LaTex?

Tags: python

Hello I typically use R but is there a way how to use stargazer in python

For example when doing an arima model

```
Model = SARIMAX(data, order = (1, 0, 0), trend = “c”
model_results = Model.fit()
Print(model_results.summary())
```

I get output table - is there a way how to convert it to latex

Comment: Some simple googling turns up: https://pypi.org/project/stargazer/ Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert the statsmodels (single model) summary to latex, you will use `summary.as_latex()`, as in `model_results.summary().as_latex()`.

If instead you want stargazed-type tables (regrouping multiple models), you will want to use the corresponding python package: https://pypi.org/project/stargazer